# Performance test of a website

Tags: performance, website

All,

How do we calculate time taken for a website to download and also from different bandwidth

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but the [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) add-on for firefox has a "Net" panel that can show you request times.
Regarding testing with different bandwidths, that's a really tricky problem, since in the real world, there are also things such as packet-loss and different round-trip times etc. to take into account. I can't recommend any specific tool, but I think it's worth pointing out that bandwidth is not the only consideration...

Comment: Yslow is great for more details in that area.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [echoping](http://echoping.sourceforge.net/) a nice program to test performances of a remote host.

Answer (score 0):

WebSiteOptimization.com has a [tool which will allow you to enter a URL](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/) and it will report on estimated download times for the HTML and all of the related images and other assets.  They will also make recommendations on how you can improve your load times.

If you're interested in improving the speed of your web site in general, I recommend two books by Steve Souders, [High Performance Web Sites](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596529309), and [Even Faster Web Sites](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596522304).